# Check if a Binary Tree <String> is aBinary Search Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search, tree

I'm understanding the question, but I want to know whether or not my implementation is correct.

The question is:

> Write a method that accepts as its argument a BinaryTree object and
>   returns true if the argument tree is a binary search tree. Examine
>   each node in the given tree only once.

This is my implementation:

```
public boolean isBST (BinaryTree<String> tree)
{
    BinaryNode Node = new BinaryNode (tree.getRootData);
    if(tree == null || Node.isLeaf() ) 
        return true;

    if(Node.getData > Node.getLeftChild && Node.getData < Node.getRightChild)
    {
        boolean leftTree = isBST(new BinaryTree(Node.getLeftChild));
        boolean rightTree = isBST(new BinaryTree(Node.getRightChild));
        return leftTree && rightTree ;
    } 
    else return false ; 
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As mariosangiorgio already said, the concept looks good, with some small improvements possible.

You should write some tests to test it. You would easily find out the mentioned problems with some good tests.

To get you an idea of a fixed version, a typical implementation could look like:

```
public boolean isBinarySearchTree(BinaryTree tree)
{
    if (tree == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tree is null");
    return isBinarySearchTree(tree.getRootNode());
}

private boolean isBinarySearchTree(Node node) // note: the name is not completely correct, because we investigate a node now. But for private and together with the other method, it would be fine
{
    if(node == null || node.isLeaf() ) //hint: node == null can only happen in one case, we could remove it here, if we change the other method
        return true;

    if (!(node.getLeftChild().getData().compareTo(node.getData()) <= 0 && 
                         node.getData().compareTo(node.getRightChild().getData()) <= 0))
        return false; // not sorted

    return isBinarySearchTree(node.getLeftChild()) && isBinarySearchTree(node.getRightChild()); 
}
```

---

A final suggestion: Avoid abbreviations.

Answer (score 4):

There are some serious problems with this function.

#### Issues of correctness

- **Code won't compile:** If `BinaryNode` indeed has fields named `getData`, `getLeftChild`, and `getRightChild` that are of type `String`, then you can't use operators `<` and `>` on them.  For strings, as with any object, you have to use `a.compareTo(b)`.
- **No consideration for unbalanced or incomplete trees:** If a node has only one child, what happens?
- **Check for `tree == null` after `tree.getRootData`:** There's no point in checking for `tree == null`, since it would have crashed on `tree.getRootData` with a `NullPointerException` already if that were the case.
- **Recursive check is insufficient:** As @user2668926 points out, you have to verify that all nodes within a subtree fall within a range of values.

#### Serious violations of style conventions

- **Using an uppercase variable name:** In Java, variable names should be `lowerCase`, except constants, which should be `ALL_CAPS`.  By naming a variable `Node`, you hurt readability tremendously by making it look like the name of a class.
- **Using `getSomething` as field names:** The convention is that `getSomething()` is the name of a getter *method* (i.e., a member *function*), usually corresponding to an instance variable named `something`.  Instead, you seem to have instance *variables* named `getRootData`, `getData`, `getLeftChild`, and `getRightChild` in your `BinaryTree` and `BinaryNode` classes, which is exceedingly weird.

I consider these two issues to be extremely serious, even if the compiler accepts the code and the algorithm runs.  These are not "merely" conventions — they are major traps for anyone else who works with your code, enough for every programmer to go facepalm.

#### Less serious issues of style

- **Distinction between `BinaryTree` and `BinaryNode`:** Wrapping nodes as trees and unwrapping the tree's root node is cumbersome.  Do you really have to make a distinction between trees and nodes?  Could you not just treat any node as a tree rooted there?
- **Use of generics:** The `BinaryTree` class is genericized, so your code should also aim to be generic.  The method signature should look something like

  ```
  public class BSTVerifier {
      public static <T extends Comparable> boolean isBST(BinaryTree<T> tree) {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

  Alternatively,

  ```
  public class BSTVerifier<T extends Comparable> {
      public boolean isBST(BinaryTree<T> tree) {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I think that having separate `BinaryTree` can make sense. You can for example keep `Count` there and it also means empty collection can work nicely.

Comment: If there are to be `BinaryTree` and `BinaryNode` classes, then I would suggest that the function be made private, and accept a `BinaryNode` argument. The public function, accepting a `BinaryTree`, can unwrap the tree's root just once and call the private version.

Answer (score 3):

The answers above are very wrong as it is NOT enough to just compare the node data with its left children and right children.  It should compare the node data with the MAX of the left subtree and compare with the MIN of the right subtree.

The so-called improved one is still very wrong.  It should have some way to record the max and min.  Check the correct answer from leetcode.

Comment: Could you provide a link to that correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation looks good but I can spot a some flaws in it.

To begin, you check that `tree == null` after having already dereferenced it at `BinaryNode Node = new BinaryNode (tree.getRootData);`.

Moreover I'd like more to see an `IllegalArgumentException` in the case of a `null` tree rather than getting the `true` answer.

I don't even get why you create a new `BinaryNode`. Why can't you use the nodes you already have in the original tree? In your implementation you try to access the left and right children but you never set them before in `Node`.

Comment: Thank You so much @mariosangiorgio for your helpful comments :) , and about the last point it's cuz i'm doing the code for a specific ADT classes i got where i cannot access the Node of the Tree unless by calling a getter method which is in BinaryNode class , and for that i need to create an object of BinaryNode class so i can call the getter method and start work on it .. Hope i could explain clear and well !~

Answer (score 0):

The below code checks if both the left and right subtrees are binary search trees, if they are then compares the nodes data with the maximum element in the nodes left subtree and minimum element in the nodes right sub tree.

```
class Node{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node(int x){
        data = x;
    }
}
public class isBST {

    public static Node getMin(Node root)
    {
        while(root.left != null)
        {
            root = root.left;
        }

        return root;
    }
    public static Node getMax(Node root)
    {
        while(root.right != null)
        {
            root = root.right;
        }

        return root;
    }
    public static boolean isBST(Node root)
    {
        // for null node
        if(root == null )
        {
            return true;
        }
        // for single node
        if(root.left == null && root.right == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // for a non null node
        if(isBST(root.left ) && isBST(root.right) )
        {
            if(root.left != null && root.right != null)
            {
            return root.data < getMin(root.right).data && root.data > getMax(root.left).data;
            }
            else 
            {
                if(root.left != null)
                {
                    return root.data > getMax(root.left).data;
                }
                else
                {
                    return root.data < getMin(root.right).data;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Node root = new Node(5);
        root.left = new Node(3);
        root.right = new Node(7);
        root.left.left = new Node(2);
        root.left.right = new Node(4);
        root.right.left = new Node(6);
        root.right.right = new Node(9);
        System.out.println(isBST(root));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  Usually we prefer to mix in some review with our code suggestions in answers.  As is, this is much more like a question than an answer.  If you do post this as a question, I think you could get some good reviews.  All you need is a title and problem statement.

Comment: hi i gave this an answer rather than question. Can u suggest any changes for this anwer?

Comment: As an answer, you should explain why you made changes from the original code.